# How do I know which website a form was filled out on?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

So I have a form embedded by 3rd party client management software.  Clients can fill out my questions and submit them to me and I get an email and the client is added to my client management software.

The problem is I have two websites and I'd like to know which one they came from and the form loads in an iframe.  Short of just asking the client what website they are on (which is bad for client experience).

I'm not sure that the form allows javascript / hidden fields or not but I can affect the iframe with javascript on the page I embed it.

Answer (score 0):

Since It's a 3rd party and it's through an iframe, you don't have much control over the process.

Is it possible for you to proxy the requests? You could have a script on your server which takes the form, records who it's from (php. `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`), and sends that along to the third party server as if the client filled it out in the survey.

I know this is kind of a hack, but it's my best idea.